# How do I override built in layout constraints on IOS / XCODE app development

Tags: ios, swift, layout, view, picker

In my IOS app, I have a Location tab. There are UIPickerViews to choose a location and a UIButton to accept the chosen location. The layout puts the button too close to the picker views and it is too easy to change the picked item when pushing the button.

I tried to move the button further away from the picker view by specifying a 50 pixel distance to the nearest picker. I added a constraint on the button to do that. But the Xcode tool finds an opposing constraint that specifies a 0 distance. The error message at run time is:

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002822da0 V:[UIPickerView:0x7fb0b2e1d5f0]-(50)-[UIButton:0x7fb0b2e1e7c0'Show on Map']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000028276b0 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIPickerView:0x7fb0b2e1d5f0]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fb0b2e1e7c0'Show on Map']   (active)>"

So this doesn't work. The second constraint was not made by me.

How can I move the button further away than 0 pixels from the pickerview.

Comment: We need to see what you're talking about... *"There are UIPickerViews ... and a UIButton ... The layout puts the button too close to the picker views ..."* What does that mean? Have you added the picker views and the button in Storyboard / Interface Builder? And you set their constraints? Or?

Comment: If you look on the left-hand sidebar in Xcode, between the file tree and the storyboard window, there should be a column of UI elements with those drop-down arrows next to them.  Try expanding the ones for the relevant UI elements, and for any constraints - this will let you see all constraints applied to those elements.  If you click on a constraint in the sidebar, it will show up in the Attributes Inspector, so you can use this to see which ones are conflicting and delete the one you don't want.  You can delete a constraint by selecting it in the sidebar and pressing the Delete key.

Comment: DonMag, This is an activity (probably wrong term), that has, top to bottom, a title "Select State, Region and Station." then three pickerviews, then two buttons underneath, the first is View on Map, the second is Select Station. I built it with the storyboard by manually placing the items.  I only used constraints to limit the heights of the pickers. It works fine but the View on Map button is too close to the Botton picker.

Comment: Quack, I have looked through those. If I add a constraint to separate the button from the picker, it accepts it. But when I run the app, and load the Location tab, the error message reproduced above occurs. The UISV-spacing constraint is being applied in error, it should be >= 0 instead of just 0.  Then the two constraints would not conflict.

Comment: @user1644002 - OK... you need to show us your layout and constraints. A `UIPickerView` has an intrinsic height... if you are not explicitly setting the heights of your picker views, it's possible there is not enough vertical space for all of your elements.

Comment: Do you want it to look like this https://imgur.com/a/HtG9CZh ?

Comment: If so, @DonMag was right about the vertical space being the problem.  What I did was set each pickerView's height to 120, and centered them horizontally.  I also centered the title and both buttons horizontally.  Then, set the separation between each picker and the next to 50; between the final picker and the top button to 50; and between the top button and the bottom button to 35. (Also 50 from title to topmost picker view)

Comment: Note that this may still be problematic on screens with a different aspect ratio!  Only tested on iPhone 14 simulator

Comment: DonMag, The height of each picker views is set to 150. The height of the title is set to 20. I see another constraint in there I didn't put there it says Region Picker.top = top + 150. Quack, the figure you show is exactly right.

Comment: I don't think DonMag got your comment: to notify a user, it only works if there's an @ right before their name - like @user1644002.  About the layout: I don't think you'll have room for everything if you make each picker 150 pixels - unless there's no space between them.  If you want it to look *exactly* like the picture, could you try testing the constraint combinations I listed in a new project?  If that works the way you want, you can edit your existing constraints instead of having to start over: open it in the Attributes Inspector and change 150 to 120, and add spaces between

Comment: Setting each pickerView's top to the bottom of the one above it, plus 50, and having the only other constraints for the picker views be the height and the horizontal centering.

Comment: @user1644002 - I suggest you put the elements (the label, the picker views, the buttons) in a vertical-axis `UIStackView`. You can then adjust the `Spacing` property to fit your design. What you might want to do is constrain the stack view's Top **and** Bottom, and set the Distribution to Equal Spacing -- that is more likely to fit nicely on different screen heights.

Comment: @DonMag That’s a great idea!

Comment: @user1644002 - this is how I laid it out, so it will "adjust to fit" all the different phone sizes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLQyB.png ... if that helps, great. If you run into any problems, I'll post an answer with some explanations.

Comment: @DonMag This is going very well now thank you. I do have one further question, about  the various stack view distributions. I sort of like to fill up the space and some of these let me do that such as equal centering.   But my buttons, while separated from the picker and the bottom like I wanted, are still pretty close together. This is a nit, now, but I'm a perfectionist. Can I move the buttons further apart.

Comment: Thank you DonMag and Quack E. Duck. You really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are seeing, UI design is much more involved than just adding components to a screen.

Via code, you can use [`setCustomSpacing(_:after:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/2866023-setcustomspacing) to "fine-tune" the layout.

You can also **embed** stack views within stack views, something like this:

[image]

[image]

I've exaggerated the vertical spacing to make the point.

View this on different iPhone sizes:

[image]

I don't know if you've considered what to do with your layout for other Traits - such as on device rotation, or when running on an iPad... or multi-tasking on an iPad - but you might end up with trait variations to get something along these lines for the layout for wide-short format:

[image]

Comment: Single best tips was look at stack view distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of micro managing the stack view layout with complicated constraints, I would just try out the stack view distribution choices. Select the stack view in the attributes inspector and choose from the choices offered, find one you like and try it on several device simulators.